# Finite volume method for 1D heat equation in 1D

Tags: finite-volume, diffusion

I wish to solve the following using the finite volume method:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{D}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)+Q(t,r)$$
with the following boundary conditions:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\Bigg|_{r=0}=0,\quad -D\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\Bigg|_{r=R}=hT(t,R)$$
Integrating the PDE (multiplied with $r$) from $r_{j-\frac{1}{2}}$ to $r_{j+\frac{1}{2}}$ to get:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{r_{j}-\frac{1}{2}}^{r_{j}+\frac{1}{2}}rudr=D\left[ r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right]_{r_{j-\frac{1}{2}}}^{r_{j+\frac{1}{2}}}+\int_{r_{j}-\frac{1}{2}}^{r_{j}+\frac{1}{2}}rQ(t,r)dr$$
I denote for general $f(t, r) $:
$$\tilde{f}_{j}(t)=\frac{1}{\delta r}\int_{r_{j}-\frac{1}{2}}^{r_{j}+\frac{1}{2}}rf(t,r)dr$$
which makes my equation:
$$\frac{d\tilde{u}_{j}}{dt}=\frac{D}{\delta r}\left[ r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right]_{r_{j-\frac{1}{2}}}^{r_{j+\frac{1}{2}}}+\tilde{Q}_{j}$$
Now is this a valid approximation?
$$r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\Bigg|_{r=r_{j+\frac{1}{2}}}=r_{j+\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\frac{\tilde{u}_{j+1}-\tilde{u}_{j}}{\delta r}$$
and likewise for the other flux. I'm also having issues with implementing the inner boundary condition at $r=0$ which is confusing me a lot.

Comment: Apparently the formula for $r \partial_r{u}$ is meant to be for $j+1/2$, otherwise it is fine, what is confusing there? For the BC at $r$=0, if it is Dirichlet type, e.g., $u$=1, then that should be no problem. For Neumann $\partial_r u =0$ should also be easy. Probably you would not want a finite (nonzero) radial derivative at $r$=0, that would make your function non-differentiable there, which would be physically possible only for a $\delta$-function source at the origin. For a more complex BC at $r$=0, it would be fine to set it at some finite (but small) distance from the origin.

Comment: Agreed with @MaximUmansky this all seems fine (besides the typo of $j+1/2$).

Comment: I'm confused about how to do the outer boundary condition. How do I link the value of u on the outer boundary to $\tilde{u}$ on the centre of the last cell?

Comment: Store your unknowns at cell centers. This means you will  not have $u$ at $r=0$ or $r=R$. You will implement the boundary conditions as fluxes. If your first unknown is $u_1$, then it will be located at $\delta r/2$.

Comment: Your definition of $\tilde f_j$ is not correct, even dimension-wise. You need to divide by $r_j$.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that?

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is, as I now realise, that you are free to compute the fluxes however you please, and the fluxes are evaluated on the cell boundaries, so I can just insert the actual values for the flux and both the inner and outer boundaries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).